# How to pass textfield data from third viewcontroller to first viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I want to send the text which is in textfield in `ViewControllerC` to another textfield which is in `ViewControllerA`

By using delegate am trying to pass the text from `ViewControllerC` to `ViewControllerA`.

i cant get the logic what to write here `delegate?.userDidEnterInformation()` in `ViewControllerC`

could any one help me regarding this

**ViewControllerC**

```
protocol DataEnteredInDestinationDelegate: class {
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String)
}

class DestinationSearchViewController: MirroringViewController {

var delegate: DataEnteredInDestinationDelegate?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        componetsTextField.text = cell?.textLabel?.text

        delegate?.userDidEnterInformation()

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

**ViewControllerA**

```
class HomeViewController: MirroringViewController, DataEnteredInDestinationDelegate
{
    func userDidEnterInformation(info: String){
        locationView.destination.text = info
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using navigation controller for view controller A and view controller C?

Comment: @Leena
am using navigationController from viewController A  to viewController B
and
navigationController from viewController B  to viewController C

Now
While coming from viewController C to viewController A, am using popToRootViewController

Comment: then you can access view controller A from the stack of navigationcontroller

Answer (score 0):

```
delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(cell!.textLabel!.text)
```

Also, you should set the delegate of `ViewControllerC`.

```
viewControllerC.delegate = viewControllerA
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to always mark delegate as `weak` e.g.:

```
weak var delegate: DataEnteredInDestinationDelegate?
```

and then you need to connect delegate like this:

```
let vcA = ViewControllerA() 
let vcC = ViewControllerC()
vcC.delegate = vcA // Connect delegate
```

and then your delegate method in ViewControllerC will work after invoking this code:

```
delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(textString)
```

Comment: this code is not working.
If i write this in ViewControllerC, it is not at all going to ViewControllerC

Answer (score 0):

Here NotificationCentre can be a good approach instead of delegates. Make Viewcontroller A an observer to receive text information as below.

Write this code in viewDidLoad()

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(userDidEnterInformation(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "UserDidEnterInformation"), object: nil)
```

and write this anywhere in class Viewcontroller A

```
func userDidEnterInformation(notification: Notification) {

    if let textInfo = notification.userInfo?["textInfo"] {
        textField.text = textInfo
    }
}
```

In Viewcontroller C post the notification with textInfo by writing below code

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.init(rawValue: "UserDidEnterInformation"), object: nil, userInfo: ["textInfo": textField.text])
```

Comment: @amma teja want to pass data using delegate pattern

Comment: according to my requirement i wrote your code like this 

func userDidEnterInformation(notification: Notification) {
        
        if let textInfo = notification.userInfo?["textInfo"] {
            locationView.destination.text = textInfo
        }
    }

am getting error in locationView.destination.text = textInfo
showing that "cannot assign value of type any to type string"

Comment: @ammateja convert textInfo to string. textInfo as? String

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:-

```
let  aVCobjA = UIViewController()
let  aVCobjB = UIViewController()
let  aVCobjC = UIViewController()

var aNavigation = UINavigationController()

func pushVC()  {
    aNavigation.pushViewController(aVCobjA, animated: true)
    aNavigation.pushViewController(aVCobjB, animated: true)
    aNavigation.pushViewController(aVCobjC, animated: true)

    //Here you will get array of ViewControllers in stack of Navigationcontroller

    print(aNavigation.viewControllers)

    //To pass data from Viewcontroller C to ViewController A

    self.passData()

}

   // To pass data access stack of Navigation Controller as navigation controller provides a property viewControllers which gives you access of all view controllers that are pushed.

func passData()  {
    let aVCObj3 = aNavigation.viewControllers.last

    let aVCObj1 = aNavigation.viewControllers[0]

    //Now you have access to both view controller pass whatever data you want to pass
}
```

Comment: i wrote this code in viewcontrollerC
how do i need to call in viewcontrollerA ?